# Extracting GZip data using C

Tags: c, gzip

How can one extract gzip data using C?

Example code

```
<layer name="Background" width="50" height="50">
 <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
  H4sIAAAAAAAAA+3YIQ6AMAwF0AEKEATwSO5/RCoRmGHY2BMvaVLzRb/pkVI6gOZ0oQ9DAVlynbd5DFOYH3Y1WcMW9gKytGbJ8HXWFtXaaQAAAAAA/s8Pm1xuBvLpDW9ciGmfRhAnAAA=
 </data>
</layer>
```

I need to extract that gzip data and continue parsing the xml (tmx) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) library that can decompress gzipped data. Before that, you'll have to decode the `base64` encoding. You can use [libbase64](http://libb64.sourceforge.net/) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you need to decode the base64 encoding to binary, thereafter use one of the free libraries to unzip like [INFO-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/).

Comment: Ok great. So once the binary is obtained, then INFO-ZIP would unzip it and export text or whatever the way it was before compression? Or is there another step after unzipping the binary?